# How to get OAuth token from CloudFoundry

Tags: oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry

I want to get data from cloud foundry using curl, but I'm not able to authenticate (oauth against CF). Please, could someone point me to and example how to get oauth token? I want to use login name and password.

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but if a recent cf cli is installed you can login as normal and then use the `cf curl` command to run raw requests.

For example

```
$ cf login (or cf auth for non-interactive login)
$ cf curl /v2/spaces/c4e73f65-4dbc-47dc-9d21-e8c566c40587/summary
```

To use actual `curl`, again using the cf cli, retrieve the bearer token with:

```
$ cf oauth-token
```

Then execute your curl command with an Authorization header:

```
$ curl --header 'Authorization: bearer ...' https://api.example.com/v2/spaces/c4e73f65-4dbc-47dc-9d21-e8c566c40587/summary
```

Comment: Hmm ... got token, but the curl returns: `{"code":10002,"description":"Authentication error","error_code":"CF-NotAuthenticated"}` ; I've used your curl example.

Comment: Make sure you have the entire token starting with bearer after the Authorization header and that it is not munged somehow. Also check to see if you are using a modern cf cli https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Answer (score 6):

Try this. I found it in the Cloud Foundry docs: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#oauth2-token-endpoint

```
curl -v -XPOST -H"Application/json" -u "cf:" --data "username=<username>&password=<password>&client_id=cf&grant_type=password&response_type=token" https://login.run.pivotal.io/oauth/token
```

Comment: note that the login api is usually served from a different subdomain than the api.  We run cf in-house, and have login.cf.ourcompany.com and api.cf.ourcompany.com

Comment: Thanks, `client_id` and `response_type` can be skipped.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already logged in using `cf`, you will find that the authorization token is stored in ~/.cf/config.json under they key "AccessToken".  You can easily pull it out of there.

If you need to get the Authorization bearer token yourself without using the `cf` CLI you can follow the instructions at https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/AppUserRegistry/index.html#appuserregistry .  You can also `export CF_TRACE=true` and then do a `cf login` yourself and watch the REST dance the CLI does with the server to get the authorization token.

Answer (score 0):

The username, password should be base 64 encoded. Url should be login endpoint of your pcf service.

```
curl https://login.<url>.com/oauth/token -X POST --user "cf:"  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d "username=<user>&password=<password>&client_id=cf&grant_type=password&response_type=token"
```