# How to execute curl operation using request module with authorizaion: bearer token?

Tags: node.js, curl, request, cloud-foundry

I am using Cloud Foundry for Bluemix app creation in that curl operations having `Authorization:bearer xxxxx` token.
How can I include **Authorization: bearer** token in request module?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985469/how-to-get-oauth-token-from-cloudfoundry "How to get OAuth token from CloudFoundry". The most easy solution is to use "cf curl" instead of "curl"

Answer (score 0):

The plain open source Clound Foundry client is able to curl the api like this:

`$ cf curl -X GET https://.../v2/...`

for instance:

`$ cf curl -X GET /v2/apps`