# How to provide credentials for calling Key Protect service within Bluemix application?

Tags: ibm-cloud, key-protect

To call the [Key Protect service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/keymgmt/index.html) API, you need to provide Authorization, Bluemix-space and Bluemix-org headers. The Authorization header contains a Bluemix access token. Such tokens can be obtained by calling 
`cf oauth-token` command (see [How to get OAuth token from CloudFoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985469/how-to-get-oauth-token-from-cloudfoundry)).

What I do not understand is:

1. What is the default validity of such a token in Bluemix?
2. If I need to call Key Protect service from a Blumeix (e.g. Liberty) application, I need to store somewhere the Authorization credentials in order to call the service. What is the best / suggested way to do that? Environment variable?  User-provided service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oauth-token returned using the cf oauth-token command is valid for the given session. However in Bluemix this session is set a validity of 1 day. You can look at the related thread here, where this is answered, https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/207063/oauth-access-token-expiry-how-to-increase-validity.html

You can refer to the Key Protect API docs here to get an understanding of how to use the APIs, with the retrieved oauth token from Bluemix, https://console.ng.bluemix.net/apidocs/639-key-protect?&language=node#retrieve-secrets-based-on-a-search-query

Comment: Thanks, but then it is really not clear how can I use Key Protect API within running application without providing every day new token? My app needs to access Key Protect API periodically to get various secrets.

Comment: One of the ways to do this is to use a cf client SDK such as this one https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client, to retrieve the token and set it as a header within your application, every time your application needs to call the Key Protect service API. You will not be able to work with one token forever, tokens have expiry.

Comment: But again it means store anywhere the id and password to get the token, like in ENV variables or custom user-provided service.