# IBM cloud list of services with their pricing info

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm looking for a list of IBM cloud services with their pricing info similar to the ones provided by Google cloud and AWS services [here](https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services?key=AIzaSyDKSAE_8nGD-5iO1p8H4_WPaSr35ZkX-Ss) and [here](https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/index.json). I looked on their website under the pricing section and I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The IBM Cloud CLI has a command to show the service offerings available to you and the available service plans](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/bx_cli.html#ibmcloud_service_offerings). The same information is available through the Cloud Foundry API. You can retrieve the service plan details through the [Service  API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/2.4.0/services/list_all_services.html) and then following the "service_plans_url", this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985469/how-to-get-oauth-token-from-cloudfoundry) shows how to use cURL with this API. Here is a public app that shows how that API and the retrieved information has been used: http://mycatalog.mybluemix.net/

Note that there is IBM Cloud Public and also dedicated versions of it (IBM Cloud Dedicated). Service pricing depends on the account type, contract type and consumption, etc.

You might want to turn tracing on to see how the CLI processes the request using the API:
`export BLUEMIX_TRACE=true; ibmcloud service offerings`

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but only lists the services with a short description and the service plan. I'm looking for a way to have the detailed pricing informations ( because ultimately I need to create my own price calculator, so I need these details) .

Comment: I digged around and I found the [Cloud Foundry API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/2.4.0/) and there is a [request](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/197/services/list_all_services.html) that list all services where for each service it includes an URL that contains the service plan details.
This answers my question. I don't know if it's allowed to answer my own question, but If it's allowed I will compose an answer.

Comment: A note on pricing calculators: From my experience it is pretty tough to be precise with graduated pricing plans, enterprise discounts on total consumption, etc. Good luck

Comment: I already suspected this project isn't going to be easy, thanks for the heads up and all the great help. Much appreciated.

Comment: IBM Cloud Foundary API is now depreceated, is there still an IBM API that can be used to retrieve pricing info for IBM Cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

today I used in addition this example command line `ibmcloud catalog pricing` with following parameter and a grep as my personal filter.

```sh
ibmcloud catalog pricing -r us-south -p paygo -k service | grep "appid" | grep "graduated-tier"
```